# Model Attribute After posting DTO Object on Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dto

In my Spring boot project, Passed a DTO object to my view which is then posted after submission. eg. How do I access the "randomKey" after the form is posted?

```
   @GetMapping("/{userId}/edit/feature/")
   public String showEditFeature(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId, UserDto userDto,
                              Model model)
   {
    User user = userService.get(userId);

    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("randomKEy", "AnyObject");

    return "user/edit/profile";
    }
```

Then My post function.

```
     @PostMapping("profile_update")
     public String watchFeatureUpdate(@Valid UserProfileDto UserProfileDto,
                                 BindingResult result,
                                 RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model)
     {
     Long userId = userService.updateUserProfile(userProfileDto);

     redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Profile features updated 
     successfully!");
     redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alertClass", "alert-success");
     return "redirect:/user/view/" + userId + "/profile";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include in your HTML page **"user/edit/profile"** as a hidden input every object property value so they are sent back when the form is submitted.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="randomKEy" value="${randomKEy}">
```

Note that HTML content is still manipulable by the user even not being visible in the rendered web page.

Comment: I have tried this, but, it doesn't work, it came out as null. It is however displayed on the page as an object, but doesn't get posted as a field.

Comment: probably you have another problem as input is out of <form> tag,  or value is not set the properly in an original GET request, or form data class property names do not match form inputs,  but every input (hidden or not) is sent when the form is posted.

Comment: jcrada, I do use hidden fields a lot, even arrays for multiple selection etc get sent, but one for object doesn't get sent AFAIK. You may try it to confirm tho. It seams Objects may not be able to rebuilt after passing out to the view. The solution may be around using Model (Model Attributes) to retrieve it back after post.

Comment: oh I see the problem now, yes you can not send back an object, you need to include all its properties value by value as inputs. Http communication simple can not magically serialize and deserialize your java objects on form submissions so you need to stick to key values pairs.